# Issue with validation in Angular JS

Tags: angularjs, validation

I have an Angular JS project. In it implemented form based on bootstrap markup (only css, without js). In the form have a telephone field for which I need to implement a validation.

Rules for validation:

1. Phone must contain only numbers, blank spaces & "+" character
2. Phone must be have minimum 11 numbers & maximum 15 numbers

Here is the code(for validation I dont use any js scripts, only angular markup):

```
<div class="row">
     <div class="col-sm-12">
          <input id="Text5"
                 name="telephone"
                 placeholder="Enter phone number (only digits or spaces)"
                 type="text"
                 ng-model="ManageDetailsCtrl.ManageDetails.Phone"
                 class="form-control"
                 style="width: 100%;"
                 ng-minlength=11
                 ng-maxlength=15
                 ng-pattern="^\+*\d{11,15}$"
                 required>
      </div>
</div>


<div class="error" ng-show="form.telephone.$dirty && form.telephone.$invalid">
     <div class="error" ng-show="form.telephone.$error.required">
          Phone number is required.
     </div>
     <div class="error" ng-show="form.telephone.$error.minlength">
          Phone number ruquired to be at least 11 characters
     </div>
     <div class="error" ng-show="form.telephone.$error.maxlength">
          Phone number cannot be longer than 15 characters
     </div>
</div>
```

The questions is follow:

1. When I'm typing numbers it isnt afflect for min & max numbers. I'm always have the error: "Phone number ruquired to be at least 11 characters"
2. Dont know how to bind regular expression. Because teoretically with already implemented 3 types of validation I may print: +1234 56789 - here is 11 characters. Maybe I need to change smth, but I dont know what.

Is anybody help me?

Comment: where is form tag..?

Comment: all of this inside the form with name form

Comment: I recommend creating a custom validator based on what you're trying to do. Then, you would have complete control over the parsing, validating, and formatting of ngModel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add `ng-class="{'has-error'}"`
PLUNKER:[HERE](http://plnkr.co/edit/Us1UzGmSw3vssQhfGhbH?p=preview)
Example:

```
<div class="form-group" ng-class="{'has-error': form.telephone.$dirty && form.telephone.$invalid}">
        <input id="Text5"
               name="telephone"
               placeholder="Enter phone number (only digits or spaces)"
               type="text"
               ng-model="ManageDetailsCtrl.ManageDetails.Phone"
               class="form-control"
               style="width: 100%;"
               ng-minlength=11
               ng-maxlength=15
               //ng-pattern="^\+*\d{11,15}$"
               required>
    <div ng-show="form.telephone.$dirty && form.telephone.$invalid">
        <span ng-show="form.telephone.$error.required" class="help-block">can't be blank</span>
        <span ng-show="form.telephone.$error.minlength" class="help-block"> is too short (min 11 characters)</span>
        <span ng-show="form.telephone.$error.maxlength" class="help-block"> is too long (max 15 characters)</span>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: please can you provide jsfiddle for it?

Comment: @BorHunter there is issue in your regex. So I have removed that. Try another regex.